# JQuery Access XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

The JQuery ajax [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) said that you can get access to the XMLHttpRequest by the following:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
          var xhrNativeObject = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
          xhrNativeObject.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) { 
               // progress bar 
          }, false);
          return xhrNativeObject;
      },
      url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
    }).then(function(response) { 
         ...         
    });
   jqxhr.abort();  // this is not working!!!
```

This is not working for me when I print jqxhr in my console I get:

```
Object {url: "http://someurl", isLocal: false, global: true, type: "POST", contentType: false…}
```

I only get the XMLHttpRequest when I do the following:

```
var myXHR;
$.ajax({
   xhr: function() { 
      myXHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest(); 
   }
 ... });
```

When I print myXHR on my console I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest {open: function, setRequestHeader: function, send: function, abort: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function…}
```

This is correct.

The JQuery docu said that I can do abort() on the jqxhr object. When do do:

```
jqxhr.abort();
```

I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'abort'
```

When I do

```
myXHR.abort();
```

everything is working.

**Why is abort() not working on the jqxhr object?**

Edit: Using JQuery 1.8.3

Edit: I created an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9HmQd/ 
      It turns out that abort is undefined when I add the then() block.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? Btw, your `jqxhr` object looks more like the options parameter, not the result of a `$.ajax()` call. Could you set up a demo that shows this behaviour?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? abort() is, in fact, a method of a jqXHR object since jQuery version 1.5

Comment: Abort is defined.  http://jsfiddle.net/gpKCn/

Comment: @Bergi Using JQuery 1.8.3

Comment: @confile - show your actual code in use, not pseudo code - you're doing something wrong if the returned object from a $.ajax call does not have an abort method.

Comment: @confile - sorry, I'm still not buying that this is your code - check this jsfiddle and open your console (http://jsfiddle.net/6VpUF/) - see how the object has an abort method?

Comment: @Adam see the jqxhr.abort() I have edited so there is the problem.

Comment: @confile My best guess is that you are somehow (in some code you are not showing us) managing to point `jqXHR` to a different object after assigning it to the return value of your $.ajax call. As @Bergi said, it looks like you are setting it to the options of the $.ajax() method at some point.

Comment: @Adam See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9HmQd/ it becomes undefined if I add the then() block.

Comment: @confile: Well, `then` does not return a jqXHR object, but a plain, non-cancelable Promise object. However, it will not have `url`, `isLocal` etc. properties as you claimed.

Comment: @Bergi So what to do?

Comment: @confile: Simply `var jqxhr = $.ajax(…), prom = jqxhr.then(transform);`?

Comment: @Bergi can you update my example: http://jsfiddle.net/9HmQd/

Comment: @confile: No. I'm confident you can do that yourself.

Comment: @Bergi this is not working see: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAeJn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.ajax()`, it returns a special kind of promise which is the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object, but when you call then on the jqxhr, it returns a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) object which will not have methods associated with jqXhr - in your case this promise is the value assigned to the `xhr` variable because of chaining.

Solution

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json'
});
xhr.then(function (response) {})

console.log(xhr.abort);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9HmQd/1/)

Comment: I see! So I should not do the chaining in one step if I want to use the abort?

Comment: Does the two step process has any impact on anything?

Comment: @confile there is no impact... both are same except for the value stored in xhr variable

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are not using the return value from the `$.ajax()` method - you are using the return value from the `then()` method - which is a promise.

By chaining `$.ajax()` immediately to `then()`, you are ultimately returning the promise object, which has no `abort()` method.

Comment: So I have to take my first solution: myXHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest(); and abort the myXHR?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are misreading the docs. The jqXHR that you are after is the one created on the return from the ajax call - as seen in various components ( complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus). An example for the docs:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { id : menuId },
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
If there is an ongoing request that takes long time then you can abort prior to completion of that request not after completion.

```
   var jqxhr = null;
    function getData(){
    if(jqxhr  != null)
    {
     jqxhr.abort();  // aborts only when an ongoing request is there.
    }

    jqxhr = $.ajax({
          xhr: function() {
              var xhrNativeObject = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
              xhrNativeObject.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) { 
                   // progress bar 
              }, false);
              return xhrNativeObject;
          },
          url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: formdata,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
        }).then(function(response) { 
             jqxhr = null;     
        });
    jqxhr = null; 
}
```